# Has there been any known improvements of Class <--> Json Serialization?

Tags: json, dart

Dart has a known error where a class you create with public variables can not be passed into native JSON template calls.  I was not sure if there has been any improved headway on this.

Example;

```
class Test{
  String a;
  int b;
}
```

would be nice to translate into:

```
{"a":"","b":0}
```

It seems when looking around the internet and forums for dart, this was an issue, and with a language that works so closely with Javascript, a terribly large oversight.  I havent seen anything yet, though it seems you might be able to scrape a the public variables if you are using mirrors, which is seemingly time intensive.

Here is what a sample is that I am working on.

```
class UserGroup{
  String a;
  int b;

  UserGroup.fromMap(Map m){ ... }
}
```

I receive from a Service call, a map which is cast to a UserGroup.

This will then produce a List which are binded and passed into a sub WebComponent which will access a Map.  Something like this.

```
<service-call result="{{rowData}}"></service-call>
<grid-creator rows="{{rowData}}"></grid-creator>
```

and inside of grid creator:

```
<dom-module id="grid-creator>
  <template>
    <div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" for="{{rows}}" as="row">
        <div id="{{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

The issue had has is that the `grid-creator` is dynamic, accepting a row of maps and parsing accordingly.  Even if I were to say `List<UserGroup> rows` it doesnt understand it as `row` and will throw an error like:

*type 'UserGroup' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'row'*

That means that Dart classes nativly cannot interact with template repeaters at all, unless the class itself is a subtype of map. which wouldnt make sense to me.

That being said, a lot of the notes are from September 2015 and prior.  I was curious where this has progressed.

You could say:  *Well, why not just have a toJson method which turns a map, then parse and intercept the class and convert it before it it hits the template.*

I mean, i guess that could be a thing if i do an observer on the `rowData` and then have a second variable which is populated and subsequently refresh the `grid-creator` but that that isnt really the point.  It sort of removes the Object from being passed around and at that point, I should just remove the class component and just use maps.  If im just using maps, then why the heck would i use dart? `/endrant`

Anyways, has there been improvements in this area?

One of the threads i was reading about serialization: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16630

**Edit:**  I was trying to look into the concept of having the class UserGroup extend JsProxy, but i dont think that would resolve the issue i was having

Comment: Maybe a general Object <-> json solution could be a complex task, but I agree sometimes the apis towards the js world could be more clear.  In the example above I can't follow the types. Lets say `List<UserGroup> rows`, then `row` will be of type `UserGroup`. But then `UserGroup` should have a `name` property, since `{{row.name}}` or?

Comment: That was all but an oversight. That was a conscious decision with good reasons. There are lots of solutions available which allow you to choose what fits best for your use case.

Comment: I was just using hand-crafted serialization/deserialization so far and therefore I'm not able to make suggestions. [dogma-xxx](https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=dogma) package was discussed a few times in the Dart Slack channel and seemed to be quite popular. Don't know which package exactly does to/from-JSON.